# django: full text search for sqlite database

Tags: django, full-text-search

I have a list of posts with a title and descrption. I have found the full text search documentation for postgres database [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/). But this is not useful for me as I am presently using sqlite3 database.

What are my options to have a similar functionality for my sqlite3 db?

Answer (score 1):

Since full-text-search is a database(PgSQL) specific tool, Django doesn't natively support for full text search in sqlite database, 
Read more on Searching in other databases

> All of the searching tools provided by django.contrib.postgres are constructed entirely on public APIs such as custom lookups and database functions. Depending on your database, you should be able to construct queries to allow similar APIs. If there are specific things which cannot be achieved this way, please open a ticket.

More: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/search/#a-database-s-more-advanced-comparison-functions

Comment: Exactly. Anyway, what would be the similar option for SQLite3 in your opinion?